# Should I register my new Apple products with Apple?

Tags: apple-id

Apple asks to register products in the installation but I am unsure whether this is a good decision. If I sell the Apple -products later, does it cause some problems? What is the point of registration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you've completed the registration, all the information you've filled up, will be sent to Apple with your iDevice / Computer's Serial Number.

Having an Apple Id associated to a Device is necessary for the **AppleCare Protection Plan**, but, if you purchased the **AppleCare** at the same time as your Device / Computer, the *Protection Plan* will be automatically registered, being unnecessary for you to do so.

The information you fulfill and submit is useful in other ways, using *Autofill* in Safari, for instance, or enable the possibilty of using the *Remind me of-doing-something when I get Home* of the iPhone 4S.

Therefore, if you want to sell your Mac or iDevice, you could just make a clean install to get rid of all that info. Not deleting it will just cause privacy / security issues.

Comment: This is not strictly true - registering your device does actually register your details with Apple for that device. But this is unlikely to cause and issues down the line. It is possible to change the registered name with Apple.

Comment: ... which is important if you also have AppleCare. AppleCare is linked to a machine with a serial number. By the way, if the machine is sold within the Applecare coverage it can be transferred to the new owner. I just did it with an iPad, no problem.

Comment: I'll edit my answer as I didn't make make my self clear at all.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this will benefit you greatly if you need support or want to check the status of your products.

You can get a better in depth registration of your products by visiting [My Support Profile](https://supportprofile.apple.com) In this portal, you can see all previous repair activity, the current status of any support cases and also the status of your warranty or Apple Care agreement.

You also have the opportunity (if you live in the US) to use Voice Pass - where you register your phone numbers and when you call support you get priority ahead of others and service tailored to you.

You can also unregister a device by clicking on it and then clicking unregister, below the devices icon.